# How would I add a knowledge base to a llama prompt?

Tags: prompt-design, llama-2

I know that the prompting format for LLAMA 2 looks like this:

```
<s>[INST] <<SYS>>
{your_system_message}
<</SYS>>

{user_message_1} [/INST] {model_reply_1}</s><s>[INST] {user_message_2} [/INST]
```

But If I want to create a knowledge base for the a given prompt, where do I put it, ie. for a question answering bot that answers question about a given story? In the system prompt, the instruction prompt or somewhere else entirely?

Comment: In order to add texts or documents to llama2 you could try looking at the easyllm library. It's possible to provide the document as context in the easyllm library. This is the relevant page on doing so:https://philschmid.github.io/easyllm/examples/llama2-rag-example/#simple-example

Comment: so it goes into the system prompt?

Comment: For this you could put the text into the instruction prompt, but there is a size limit. I don't think that would be the best way to do this if you have pretty large documents. I would suggest that you look for something that can do this specific task.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you [retrieval augmented generation (RAG)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.11401). This approach has its advantages in knowledge intensive task. There are several tutorial in the web based on huggingface.

A part of RAG is prompt engineering. You embed your query and search for similarity in your vector database. The results are the top-k similar documents. It's important to split the documents into chunks or in sentence.
The return documents of the similarity search can append to your prompt as context.

As instance:

```
Use the following pieces of context to answer the question at the end.
  If you don't know the answer, just say that you don't know, don't try to make up an answer.
  You have to act like investor on the wall street and answer the question like that.
  Context: {context}
  Question: {query}
  Helpful Answer:
```

```
complete_prompt = template.format(context=", ".join(text_list), query = query)
```

Comment: still doesn't tell me in which spot of the llama 2 prompting format I gotta put the RAG retrieved text.

Comment: Not in the system prompt.  You can put the context as "user message", because you can pass context as user, also.